# Делаю в VS2012 C++ по примеру из Borland C++ Builder, выдает ошибку LNK2019

Tags: c++, usb

Здравствуйте. Постепенно перепечатываю пример программы на ПК из http://we.easyelectronics.ru/electro-and-pc/usb-dlya-avr-chast-2-hid-class-na-v-usb.html

Использующий библиотеку hidlibrary.h https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4Hgd/mWysiTyRH

Программа написана в Borland C++ Builder 6, я пишу в консольном приложении MVS2012, опуская визуальную часть.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "hidlibrary.h"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

// Вытягиваем имена устройства из проекта контроллера.
#include "usbconfig.h"
char  vendorName[]  = {USB_CFG_VENDOR_NAME, 0}; // для того что бы знать как
char  productName[] = {USB_CFG_DEVICE_NAME, 0}; // называется наше устройство


struct dataexchange_t      
{
   unsigned char  b1;        
   unsigned char  b2;        
   unsigned char  b3;        
};                  
struct dataexchange_t pdata = {0, 0, 0};

HIDLibrary <dataexchange_t> hid; 

int connect()  // этой функцией будем подключаться к устройству
{
   volatile int n, res=0;
   string exampleDeviceName = "";

   exampleDeviceName += vendorName;
   exampleDeviceName += " ";
   exampleDeviceName += productName;

   n = hid.EnumerateHIDDevices(); 

   return res;
}


int main (int)
{



    system("pause");
}
```

Дошел до строки

```
n = hid.EnumerateHIDDevices()
```

При добавлении ее, столкнулся с ошибками ниже. По причинам необразованности исчерпывающую информацию дать не могу, банально не знаю что, но добавлю по запросу.

```
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList@4 referenced in function "public: int __thiscall HIDLibrary<struct dataexchange_t>::EnumerateHIDDevices(void)" (?EnumerateHIDDevices@?$HIDLibrary@Udataexchange_t@@@@QAEHXZ)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces@20 referenced in function "public: int __thiscall HIDLibrary<struct dataexchange_t>::EnumerateHIDDevices(void)" (?EnumerateHIDDevices@?$HIDLibrary@Udataexchange_t@@@@QAEHXZ)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailA@24 referenced in function "protected: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall HIDLibrary<struct dataexchange_t>::GetDevicePath(void *,struct _SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA *)" (?GetDevicePath@?$HIDLibrary@Udataexchange_t@@@@IAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PAXPAU_SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA@@@Z)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiGetClassDevsA@16 referenced in function "public: int __thiscall HIDLibrary<struct dataexchange_t>::EnumerateHIDDevices(void)" (?EnumerateHIDDevices@?$HIDLibrary@Udataexchange_t@@@@QAEHXZ)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setupapi.lib нужно добавить в проект

Comment: 1ой строчкой все решили, спасибо.